# how to print below pattern there is no tables in database

Tags: mysql, sql

How to print this pattern in mysql or sql without use any tables in database.

```
1  1
2  1
2  2
3  1
3  2
3  3
4  1
4  2
4  3
4  4
```

Comment: see it vertical two lines,its like 1 give 1 and 2 give 1,2. and 3 give 1,2,3 and

Comment: `select '1 1 2 1 2 2 3 1 3 2 3 3 4 1 4 2 4 3 4 4'` . You usually get as much in answer as you put into the question.

Comment: Thumbs up @pinegulf

Comment: With formattin: `select '1 1' union select '2 1' union select '2 2'  ` and so forth.

Comment: without union i want,can we print

Answer (score 2):

```
select sq2.n, sq.n 
from (select 1 n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) sq 
join (select 1 n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) sq2 
  on sq.n <= sq2.n
order by sq2.n, sq.n;


+---+---+
| n | n |
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
+---+---+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In MySQL 8, when MySQL supports `WITH` clause, you can also write it as

```
with sq as (select 1 n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4)
select sq2.n, sq.n
from sq
join sq as sq2
on sq.n <= sq2.n
```

Comment: please explain this query

Comment: @UmmeHabibaQadri What part? is just join two tables and make sure the sequence of second number isnt bigger than the first number.

Comment: fancy I add the order by to make sure the query return on the order request it, But you invert the {sq2, sq}  order and is a little confusing.

Comment: @UmmeHabibaQadri What is unclear about the query?

Comment: thanks,its clear to me